# Copy/Paste content of a Jupyter code cell into a xterm/uxterm terminal

Tags: firefox, jupyter-notebook, x11, copy-paste, jupyter-lab

I am trying to copy the code of a Jupyter Lab cell into uxterm.
Traditionally you just select (highlight) the text with the mouse and then click the middle button of the mouse in the terminal (or in any other X11 application) and the highlighted content is pasted there.

In Jupyter-Lab this works if you copy Markdown content or output content, but not if you try to copy and paste the actual code of a code cell.

Anyone (maybe in Linux, I am using FreeBSD) having the same issue? Any tips on how to solve it?

I do not know if the issue is specific to Jupyter-Lab, Jupyter, or Firefox. I am using Octave kernel, but I think that is irrelevant.

Edit: if I convert the cell into a Markdown cell, execute it so Markdown is displayed, then I can copy the code normally and paste into uxterm. It seems an issue with the copy function of Jupyter-Lab for code cells. Other websites can copy/paste in X11 normally.